# Enhanced perfomance on second execution perl

Tags: performance, perl, ubuntu, caching

I have a perl script that is running rather slow and I want to improve it's performance by improving the code efficiency.

When I run the script with some parameters for a first time, it runs for about 6 minutes. However, when I run it for a second time (with the same parameters), it only takes about 5 seconds.

I guess the results are cached, causing the script to run much faster after the first execution.
However, I don't want this! I want the script to run as slow as the first time, every time, so I can find out what part of my code is the inefficient bottleneck and test while improving it.

Can I in some way clear the cached results to get more or less the same performance on every subsequent execution? Or prevent Perl from caching in the first place (if would be Perl that's doing the caching)?

I'm running the script on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: There's no general caching mechanism in Perl. Read the script, find out how it caches the results, remove the cache / intercept the creation. Without seeing the code, we can't give you more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question is flawed. To find the bottlenecks, you just need to execute the script once. See [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::NYTProf).